# Filtering millions of files with pySpark and Cloud Storage

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am facing the following task: I have individual files (like Mb) stored in Google Cloud Storage Bucket grouped in directories by date (each directory contains around 5k files). I need to look at each file (xml) , filter proper one and put them into Mongo or write back to Google Cloud Storage in lets say parquet format. I wrote a simple pySpark program that looks like this:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName('myApp')
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://<mongo_connection>") 
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.database", "test") 
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.collection", "test")
    .config("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
    .getOrCreate()
)

spark_context = spark.sparkContext
spark_context.setLogLevel("INFO")
sql_context   = pyspark.SQLContext(spark_context)

# configure Hadoop
hadoop_conf = spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")


# DataFrame schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField('filename', StringType(), True),
    StructField("date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("xml", StringType(), True)
])

# -------------------------
# Main operation
# -------------------------
# get all files
files = spark_context.wholeTextFiles('gs://bucket/*/*.gz')

rows = files \
    .map(lambda x: custom_checking_map(x)) \
    .filter(lambda x: x is not None)

# transform to DataFrame 
df = sql_context.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

# write to mongo
df.write.format("mongo").mode("append").save()

# write back to Cloud Storage
df.write.parquet('gs://bucket/test.parquet')

spark_context.stop()
```

I tested it on a subset (single directory `gs://bucket/20191010/*.gz`) and it works. I deploy it on Google Dataproc cluster, but doubt anything is happening single the logs stop after `19/11/06 15:41:40 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1573054807908_0001`

I am running 3 worker cluster with 4 cores and 15GB RAM + 500GB HDD. Spark version 2.3.3, scala 2.11 mongo-connector-spark_2.11-2.3.3.
I am new to Spark so any suggestions are appreciated. Normally, I would write this work using Python multiprocessing, but wanted to move to something "better", but now I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

It could take significant amount of time to list very large number of files in GCS - most probably your job "hangs" while Spark driver listing all files before starting processing.

You will achieve much better performance by listing all directories first and after that processing files in each directory - to achieve best performance you can process directories in parallel, but taking into account that each directory has 5k files and your cluster only 3 workers, it could be good enough to process directories sequentially.